# Square from \end{proof} displaying incorrectly

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

Often, when I'm ending my proofs, the square generated by \end-proof is coming in new line for no reason.
I'm using the vanilla proof environment with a couple enumerates and a lot of text inside.
And most of the times it's displaying correctly, but in some instances it isn't.

```
                 \item(Identity) let (X,A) be in object of QUnif and                         
                                 etc etc               
              \end{enumerate}                                                                        
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case you have to use `\qedhere` before `\end{enumerate}`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks! that solved it.